# Convert DateTimePicker to Unix, and Back again

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker, unix-timestamp

Is there any easy solution for translating a unix timestamp like this:

```
1350664800
```

Into a human readable date like:

```
10/19/2012 11:40 AM
```

?

I'm working on alerting the jQuery UI [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) (with [datetimepicker addon](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)) so that it selects and displays the 'human' date, sends the unix date to the server, then translates it back to the 'human date' on open. I have the translation going with this function:

```
        function unixTranslate() {
            $('input[name=valueTextField]').each(function () {
                var unixTimestamp =  ($(this).datetimepicker("getDate").getTime() / 1000) + 3600;
                $(this).attr('title', unixTimestamp);          
             });
    }
```

Which outputs the correct number from the datetimepicker widget, but I'm not sure how to translate it back.

**Edit**

Okay, so I have it converting back to a JS date object with this:

```
   var myDate = new Date(unixTimestamp * 1000);
        alert(myDate);
```

However, now I'm having an issue parsing it to make it look like how I want. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something (a bit messy) like this should get the job done:

```
var date = new Date(unixTimestamp * 1000),
//generate formatted string
formatted = (date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear() + " " + (date.getUTCHours() > 12 ? date.getUTCHours()-12 : date.getUTCHours()) + ":" + date.getUTCMinutes() + " " + (date.getUTCHours() >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
var date = new Date(unixTimeStamp * 1000);
alert(date.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: This is very close, but doesn't give the exact format I was looking for. Thank you though!